# Spectrum of two operators on Hilbert Space whose difference is compact

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, and $v$ and $w$ two elements of $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}),$ the space of the continuous linear operators from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}.$ 
All we know is that $u=w-v$ is a compact operator.
Prove that $Sp(w)-Vp(w)\subset Sp(v).$

All I can think about is to consider $\lambda \in Sp(w)-Vp(w)$ and $h$ such that $h\notin Im(w-\lambda Id),$ or to consider $u=w-v=w-\lambda Id-v+\lambda Id,$ but every approach of this kind doesn't bring me anywhere.
Thanks a lot!

Edit: Sp(w) is the spectrum of the operator $w,$ i.e. the set $\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C} | w-\lambda \text{Id} \ \text{not invertible} \},$ whereas $Vp(\lambda)=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C} | w-\lambda \text{Id} \ \text{not injective} \}.$

Comment: I assume $Sp(w) =$ the spectrum of $w$, correct?  But then what is $Vp(w)$? Thanks!

Comment: I'm really sorry, my bad! Just edited the file. (Actually I realized that $Vp$ is just a french notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found a solution.
Let $\lambda$ be a number such that $w-\lambda Id$ is injective but not invertible.
So, we want to show that also $v-\lambda Id=w-u-\lambda Id$ is not invertible.

By absurd, if it was invertible, we would be able to write:
$$ w-\lambda Id=w-u-\lambda Id +u= (w-u-\lambda Id)(Id+u')$$ with $u':=(w-u-\lambda Id)^{-1}u,$ a  compact operator which exists by invertibility of $(w-u-\lambda Id).$

Because $w-\lambda Id$ is injective, so it is $Id+u',$ and by compactness of $u'$ we obtain by a well-known lemma that $Id+u'$ is also surjective.

But this would mean that $w-\lambda Id$ is surjective, and thus invertible, which leads to a contradiction.